# django __str__ returned non-string(type tuple)

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hello  i'm studying django, and

i have a problem with def **str** on models

```
models.py

class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    school_year  = models.CharField(max_length=4,choices=SCHOOL_YEAR_CHOICES,default='2019')    
    campus = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CAMPUS_CHOICES,default='M')  
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=TYPE_CHOICES,default='N')  
    affiliate = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=AFFILIATE_CHOICES,default='N')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name,self.campus


class Comment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=ABOUT_CHOICES,default='L')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_by.first_name, self.student.name
```

if i remove that " student = models.ForeignKey ~~" on class Comment,  it'll work

i think 'student' on class comment makes a problem

anyone help? thanks

and  i'm using python3 with the lastest version of django

Comment: Where is first_name?

Comment: As the error says, you return a tuple in your `__str__`. You need to return a string. Therefore, if you want to return `self.name` and `self.campus` you should use `return "{0} - {1}".format(self.name, self.campus)`, or a similar format. Also make sure to change the `return` of the `Comment` model.

Comment: thanks but class Student no problem , class Comment are problem .  self.student.name makes a prolem i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this on Comment model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.created_by.first_name + ' ' + self.student.name
```

Also on Student model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ' ' + self.campus
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name+' '+self.campus
```

Comment: thanks but class Student no problem , class Comment are problem .  self.student.name makes a prolem i think

Comment: There is problem in both `__str__`. `__str__` in Comment should also be redefined. There is no `User` model so I don't no if there is `first_name` field.

Comment: so you mean, i should redefine Class students Using User right?      anyway self.created_by.first_name isn't problem,

Comment: No. In class Comment You have two foreignKeys, first is connected with `Student` model, second with `User`. So, You should add definition of `User` model or connect both foreignKeys from `Comment` with model `Student`.

Comment: but class Student are just list for me , i mean students list     should i connect with user? is there other solutions?

Comment: i just wanted to possible make Students list by any teacher, and any teacher be able to add comment on student one by one

Comment: Once again: You have big mess in code. Read `models.py` line by line. In `class Comment` there is `created_by` field which is connected with `User`, but there is no definition of class `User`...